# Benefit of non-empty method of non-abstract class and abstract method of abstract method?

Tags: oop, abstract

I don't understand why we use abstract method (abstract class) while we can use empty method of non-abstract class and then we override it. Does it sound fine? I am seeking to clarify this issue.

I give 2 examples

```
public abstract class MyClass {public abstract void foo();}
public MyChildClass extends MyClass {public void foo() {//..TODO}}

public class MyClass {public void foo(){//empty}}
public class MyChildClass extends MyClass {public void foo() {//..TODO}}
```

Which one is better?

Comment: For starters, the abstract option makes the compiler **force** you to override it, which is great down the line when someone else (or yourself) may forget to place the proper override. The non-abstract option is better for "optional" methods, like notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by saying that you should try to use interfaces instead of abstract classes. Abstract classes couple the subclass to the implementation of the superclass. In a language like Java, the subclass can override any method even if the superclass did not intend to do so, and most people don't qualify their methods with "do not override" all the time.

At the lowest level, abstract methods give you two concrete protections at compile time:

- They force you to override the method in a subclass
- They disallow the creation of the abstract class

Before listing the use cases for abstract methods, I'll just say that "common functionality" is NOT a good reason for an abstract base class. If you need common functionality, just create a class that has the common methods, and let the various classes call these functions as they see fit.

So when *would* you use an abstract class? Here are some examples:

### Template Method

In the template method pattern, you have all of your functionality, but there's just one internal aspect that's polymorphic, so you have subclasses that override that particular aspect.

For example, if you're implementing a cache, but the cache invalidation policy is polymorphic, you may have an abstract `invalidate()` method that is called internally by other methods, but it's up to subclasses to implement `invalidate()`.

If there is a preferred default cache invalidation policy, then `invalidate()` could implement that default. But if that default is downright destructive in some cases, then it shouldn't be a default - it should be abstract, and the code that creates the cache should be forced to explicitly choose the invalidation policy.

This can also be achieved by passing an `Invalidator` class to the constructor (Strategy pattern), but if the invalidation logic needs to call methods of the cache, it's better to make those method protected and call them from a subclass (i.e. Template Method pattern).

### Default implementation of other methods

In languages where interfaces cannot have default methods (e.g. Java 7), you can emulate it using abstract classes. All the interface methods will be abstract, but the default methods would be regular public methods.

### Common Interface and Functionality

This is just a more generic version of the template method pattern. The difference is that the polymorphic methods are part of the API.

If your common functionality has a lot of overlap with the functionality you want to expose, and you don't want mountains of boilerplate code, you use an abstract class. For example:

```
interface File {
    abstract Buffer read(int size);
    abstract void write(Buffer buf);
    abstract long getSize();
    abstract void setSize();
    // ... get/set creation time, get/set modification time, get
    // file type etc.
    abstract long getOwner();
    abstract void setOwner(long owner);
}

abstract class AbstractFile extends File {
    DataMap dataMap;
    MetadataMap metaMap;
    protected getDiskMap() { return dataMap; }
    protected getMetaMap() { return metaMap; }
    public Buffer read(int size) { /* loop here */ }
    public void write(Buffer buf) { /* loop here */ }
    public long getSize() { /* logic */ }
    public void setSize() { /* logic */ }
    // ... implementation of get/set creation time, get/set modification
    // time, get file type etc.
}

abstract class HardDriveFile extends AbstractFile {
    OwnershipMap ownerMap;
    abstract long getOwner() { /* logic */ }
    abstract void setOwner(long owner) { /* logic */ }
}

abstract class ThumbDriveFile extends AbstractFile {
    // thumb drives have no ownership
    abstract long getOwner() { return 0; }
    abstract void setOwner(long owner) { /* no-op */ }
}

abstract class SomeOtherfile extends AbstractFile {
    ...
}
```

If we cut the middleman and have `HardDriveFile` and `ThumbDriveFile` (and possibly other types of files) implement `File` and spell out all the common methods, each calling a method of some common class, we would get mountains and mountains of boilerplate. So we inherit from an abstract base class, that has the abstract methods we want to specialize (e.g. based on the existence of an ownership map).

The naive thing to do would be to combine `File` and `AbstractFile` into a single class, which is where you'd get the abstract methods `getOwner()` and `setOwner()`, but it's better to hide abstract classes behind actual interfaces, to prevent the coupling between consumers of an API and the abstract class.